# Putting values and characters inside a bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data set:

```
    >x1
      col1 col2 col3
   1    0    8  100
   2  0.1    5  200
   3  0.2    3  300
   4  0.3    1  400
```

I generate the bar graph as this:

```
ggplot(x1[,1:2],aes(x=col1, y=col2)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity") +
 ggtitle("plot1")
```

The generated graph looks like as this

[image]

At present, each bar is solid. However, I would like to make it as transparent, and superimpose the value in the third column onto each corresponding bar. In the following, I show the draft that I would like to see. But how to do that with ggplot?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
ggplot(x1, aes(x = col1, y = col2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "transparent", colour = "black")+
  ggtitle("plot1") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste("$", col3)), vjust = 2)
```

The `fill` colour of the bars is removed with the argument `fill = "transparent"`. Black borders are created with `colour = "black"`.

The function `geom_text` is used to add text to the plot. Here, `vjust` can be used to modify the vertical position of the labels.

[image]